# Is it possible to create a custom View of images?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a simple layout of images where it can be viewed in columns and rows like a table. Does anyone know if this is possible

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 0):

Grid View Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


 // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {

            //R.drawable.1
        R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,
        R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,
        R.drawable.g,R.drawable.f,
        R.drawable.h,R.drawable.i,
        R.drawable.j,R.drawable.k,
        R.drawable.l,R.drawable.m

    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
            return imageView;


    }


}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
              Button btnNavigate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

              btnNavigate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SpinnerDemo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
                // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
                gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        }
```

Many Demos are available on androidhive.info

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

**Layout file :**

> ```
>   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>        android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>      tools:context=".MainActivity" >
> <GridView
>     android:id="@+id/gridView1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:columnWidth="90dp"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
>     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
>     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
>     android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
>     android:layout_below="@+id/Linearlayout">
> </GridView>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/Linearlayout"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Button" />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button2"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Button" />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button3"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>        android:text="Button" />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button4"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Button" />
> </LinearLayout>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
>     android:text="TextView" />
>   </RelativeLayout>
> ```

**AdapterClass**

> ```
>      public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
>   private Context mContext;
> // Keep all Images in array
> public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
>     R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
>         R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
>         R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
>         R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher
> };
> // Constructor
> public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
>     mContext = c;
> }
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     return mThumbIds.length;
> }
> @Override
> public Object getItem(int position) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     return mThumbIds[position];
> }
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     return 0;
> }
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
>     imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
>     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
>     imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
>     return imageView;
> }
> }
> ```

Call the adapter class to bind the data into GridView as below in your activity

> ```
>  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     GridView m_grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
>     m_grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
> }
> ```
>
> }